# How to convert a date string to a MySQL DATETIME?

Tags: perl, datetime-format

How can I convert

```
12/22/13 21:48:06
```

to the MySQL `DATETIME` format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito This question is tagged **Perl**, not **PHP**, and that question asks how to convert *from* a MySQL DATETIME *to* another format, the exact opposite of this question. This question is probably a dupe, but is definitely **not** a dupe of the question you listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my ($m,$d,$y,$T) = $orig_dt =~ m{^(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\z}
   or die "Error";

my $mysql_dt = "20$y-$m-$d $T";
```

Or if you don't need any validation,

```
my ($m,$d,$y,$T) = split(/[\/ ]/, $orig_dt);
my $mysql_dt = "20$y-$m-$d $T";
```

or

```
my $mysql_dt = sprintf('20%3$s-%1$s-%2$s %4$s', split(/[\/ ]/, $orig_dt));
```

Answer (score 5):

[DateTime::Format::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~cfaerber/DateTime-Format-DBI-0.041/lib/DateTime/Format/DBI.pm) can convert [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.05/lib/DateTime.pm) objects to the appropriate string representation for the database engine you're using. This is nice because it allows you to switch RDBMS's without having to rewrite your date parsing code.

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::DBI;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( ... ) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $date = '12/22/13 21:48:06';
my $str_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%D %T');

# Parse string into a DateTime object
my $dt = $str_parser->parse_datetime($date);

my $db_parser = DateTime::Format::DBI->new($dbh);

$dbh->do("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)", undef,
         $db_parser->format_datetime($dt));

# For MySQL, inserts 2013-12-22 21:48:06
```

This may be overkill for what you're working on but could be handy for projects where you need to connect to multiple types of database simultaneously, for example. IBM DB2, Microsoft SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, and Sybase are currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for parsing and formatting dates is [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html#Date-Parsing), which has been a core module since Perl 5.9:

```
use Time::Piece;

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime('12/22/13 21:48:06', '%D %T');
print $t->strftime('%F %T');
```

#### Output:

```
2013-12-22 21:48:06
```